# Finding all possible paths in a cyclic directed graph given a starting vertex and a depth limitation

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, directed-graph

Consider the directed cyclic graph given below;

[image]

If a starting point (eg: vertex 0) and a maximum depth allowed is specified (eg: 5), what algorithm can be used to find all possible paths (note: a given vertex can be visited more than once)?

What is the most efficient algorithm to implement this graph problem?

Some of the possible paths for the above graph are given below in no particular order (starting with vertex 0 and maximum depth allowed is 5).

- 0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 4 -> 1 -> 3
- 0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 4 -> 5 -> 1
- 0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6
- 0 -> 1 -> 3 -> 5 -> 1 -> 3

Comment: build a new graph with nodes (u, depth) and edges from (u, depth) to (v, depth +1) according to original graph, then just to BFS/DFS to find all paths from starting node (u,0) to all nodes (x, maxDepth)

Comment: I think you can just augment a BFS to also keep track of the depth. When it has hit the right depth, add the path (kept in memory) to the path collection.

Comment: Note that your problem is NP-hard. See [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/423/how-hard-is-counting-the-number-of-simple-paths-between-two-nodes-in-a-directed), [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/118664/find-all-nodes-on-simple-paths-between-two-nodes-in-cyclic-directed-graph) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1938073/exact-bound-on-the-number-of-simple-paths-in-a-graph).

Comment: @LiorKogan So even though there might be an algorithmic solution, will the algorithm that I'll be implementing grow exponentially? What sort of time complexity will I be looking at?

Comment: @shapiroyaacov my initial idea was this, but this looked like a very brute force approach to me. Is there any way of optimizing the approach?

Comment: @Ashera: For a Clique of size n and maximal depth n: O(n!).

Comment: @Ashera this will add each path exactly once which is what you need. Can't do any less. also for a Clique, you'll need al `O(n!)` paths...

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo algorithm for this will be an augmented BFS that keeps track of the path it has gone through. When it hits the required depth, it registers the path and then terminates.

Something like this (node.js style syntax):

```
const requiredDepth = X
const relevantPaths = {}

const runBFS = (curNode, curPath = []) => {
    if (crPath.length === requiredDepth) {
        relevantPaths.push(curPath)
        return
    }

    for (let neighbor of curNode.neighbors) {
        const newPath = [ ...curPath, getEdge(curNode, neighbor) ]
        runBFS(neighbor, newPath)
    }
}

runBFS(root)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your quick response:) I get the basic idea of what you are suggesting. But how exactly will duplicates come into the picture? Is it because the same node can be visited more than once? If that's what you're implying, and if duplicates were actually a possibility, this algo would never terminate (when considering a graph with cycles). Anyways, a simple workaround with duplicates would be to check before pushing to the `relevantPaths` right?

Comment: @Ashera you're right. There will be no duplications. I'll edit that now